# insert con validacion en SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Hola tengo una base de datos en sqlite y sucede que debo añadir campos a una tabla que contiene un id "integer primary key unique", el id no puede ser incrementable por otras cuestiones. Los datos que le agrego a la tabla los descargo de un webservice, ahora necesito saber como hacer una validación para que muestre al usuario un mensaje de "dato ya insertado".

En el webservice un admin ingresa datos y en la app de android un usuario los descarga a través de un botón. Puede que el admin ingrese un dato un día, y otro dato otro día, y en la app solo debe descargarse el "nuevo dato."
Aquí dejo el código

```html
listCreditos = Response.List_Creditos_All;//listCreditos es un list que guarda todos los registros obtenidos del webservice

//Despues se hace una consulta a la tabla sqlite
bd = con.getReadableDatabase();
tring query = "Select * from " + _inicio.TInicio + " where idusuario= '" + Request.IdUsuario + "'";
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

if (cursor.getCount() == 0)//si la tabla esta vacia insertara los datos sin problema
{
 for (int i = 0; i < listCreditos.size(); i++)
 {
 inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
//se guardaran en un metodo ya establecido
con.creditos(inicio.getId(), inicio.getMonto(), inicio.getMontoActual(), inicio.getLocalidad(), inicio.getMunicipio(), inicio.getCP(), inicio.getEstado());

}
return true;
}
}

//si la tabla tiene 1 o mas registros 
else if (cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
//aqui guardo cada dato en el modelo de mi tabla
inicio = new Inicio(inicio);             
inicio.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_inicio.id))); 
....//
)));
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
cursor.close();
```

Ahora ¿Cómo debería hacer una validación para que guarde solo aquellos registros que no existen en mi tabla sqlite?.

Answer (score -1):

Código:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

es para incrementar. Pero ojo que empieza desde 1 en adelante.

Cuando sea verdadero por un toast

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Dato ya Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```